# How to implement multiple callouts in MKPinAnnotationView

Tags: ios

This is my first ever question on stack-overflow and also I am new iOS development.
I am developing a map application for my school. my school has 25 buildings. I have 25 MKPinAnnotationViews in my map.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
// if it's the user location, just return nil.
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

// handle our two custom annotations
//
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[SchureAnnotation class]]) // for Harry Schure Hall
{
    // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
    static NSString* SchureAnnotationIdentifier = @"schureAnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
    [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:SchureAnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        // if an existing pin view was not available, create one
        MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                               initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:SchureAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

        // add a detail disclosure button to the callout which will open a new view controller page
        //
        // note: you can assign a specific call out accessory view, or as MKMapViewDelegate you can implement:
        //  - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control;
        //
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(showDetails:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        return customPinView;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}
else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[SaltenAnnotation class]]) // for Salten Hall
{
    // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
    static NSString* SaltenAnnotationIdentifier = @"saltenAnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
    [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:SaltenAnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        // if an existing pin view was not available, create one
        MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                               initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:SaltenAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
 ..........
```

I want to put a different callout to show its information for each pin. I am calling the function  showDetails: which looks like this

```
- (void)showDetails:(id)sender
{
// the detail view does not want a toolbar so hide it
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Inorder to show the information of each building, do I need to write 25 view controllers? or is there anyway to use one view controller? If I click on right button of the annotationview, it has to show its information(picture, text). If I click on another annotation it has to show its information by replacing the old one.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Pradeep.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the 
`[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Change to

`[rightButton addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

And then:

Step 1:

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TCServiceStationDetailFromMap" sender:view];
}`

Step 2:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TCServiceStationDetailFromMap"]) {

```
    MKAnnotationView *view = sender;
    TSPlaceMark *detailPlaceMark = (TSPlaceMark *)view.annotation;
    //...
    //so that you can get the different MKAnnotationView  
}
```

}